# Как изменить сортировку ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите как можно сделать сортировку по убыванию и возрастанию, кликая по одному и тому же элементу?
Например, есть сортировка по имени. Нажали 1 раз - сортировка по убыванию, якорек меняет цвет через background на желтый(якобы активная сейчас сортировка по убыванию, можно посмотреть на примере при hover), нажали 2-й раз - сортировка по возрастанию и также изменили положение якорька(повернули кончиком вверх)
Я сделал, но только разделил на 2 части( Имя(А-Я) / Имя(Я-А), а это мне не подходит. Хочется как выше описал.
Данные выводятся через блоки, а не в таблицу.

```js
$(".list p").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#load").fadeIn(1000,function () {
      $.ajax({
        url:'/index.php',
        data:'sortby_id='+id,
        type:'get',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(html) {
          $("#main").html('');
          for(value in html) {
             $("#main").append(
                        'тут добавляются данные через верстку. Не буду писать'
                      );
                }
          $("#main").hide().fadeIn(2000);
          $("#load").fadeOut(1000);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
ul, li {margin: 0 12px; padding:0; list-style: none;float:left;}
.sort_bar li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(252,252,252,.3);
}
.sort_sub:after {
  background: url(http://s017.radikal.ru/i431/1510/18/2123728d15bd.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  position: absolute;
}
.sort_sub:hover:after {
  background: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i710/1510/1e/b47e2acf1f7c.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<span>Сортировка: </span>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
     <li><p class="sort_sub" id="raiting">Заголовок</p></li>
     <li><p class="sort_sub" id="name">Название</p></li>
     <li><p class="sort_sub" id="price">Цена</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Маленький запрос sql при примера как делал

```
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM books';
  if($id) {
    if($id == 'name') {
      $query .= ' ORDER BY name ASC';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если проблема только в этом, я бы применил .toggleClass().

JS:

```
$(".list p").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('alpha-desc');
});
```

CSS:

```
.list p::after{
    content: ' (А-Я)';
}
.list p.alpha-desc::after{
    content: ' (Я-А)';
}
```

По просьбе, пример передачи и обработки массива:
JS

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/index.php',
    type:'get',
    data: {
        sortby_id:{
            name: 'asc',
            title: 'asc',
            price: 'desc'
        } //поле: направление
    },
    .....
});
```

РНР:

```
$allowed = array('title', 'name', 'price'); //разрешенные колонки
$order = array(); //массив условий
foreach ($_GET['sortby_id'] as $column=>$dir) {
    if (!in_array($column, $allowed)) continue; //неизвестная колонка пропускается
    $order[] = $column.' '.($dir=='desc'?'desc':'asc');
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM books';
if (!empty($order)) {
    $query .= ' ORDER BY '.implode(',',$order);
}
```

Решение не тестировал, возможно, где-то ошибка. Но направление, думаю, понятно.

Comment: мне необходимо, чтобы просто писало "Цена", и при клике на "Цена" сам якорек изменял цвет и положение("носик" треугольника смотрит в зависимости от сортировки). Ну и естественно, данные из бд сортировались. Это видимо надо еще sql код отписать какой. Изменил первый пост. Теперь посмотрите как показан стиль

Comment: При клике на "Цена" переключайте класс, как я показал выше, и задавайте в зависимости от этого цвет и положение. Только в случае с картинкой Вам понадобится аж 4 разных изображения (или спрайт из 4х частей). Лучше попробовать символы: ▲ ▼. Проблем со SQL я у Вас не вижу. Аналогично для всех полей - и будет результат.

Comment: У меня по стилю не подойдут такие символы( А как быть с sql запросом?
У меня на данном этапе 3 проверки id = name, price, title.

Comment: Есть несколько других способов создать объект-треугольник, вот некоторые: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1538 Сейчас для вывода простых фигур лучше обходиться без изображений. SQL у Вас будет выглядеть примерно так: SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY name ASC, price ASC, title DESC (для примера)

Comment: Спасибо за направление. Сейчас попробую разобраться. Но в любом случае будет 6 запросов? Сначала проверка на class без изменений и идет сортировка по ASC , а затем проверка на класс с добавлением class alpha-desc по DESC? В итоге, 6 запросов?
Например, первый: 
` 
if($id) {
    if($id == 'name') {
      $query .= ' SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY name ASC, price ASC, title DESC';
    }
  }
`
А второй вариант 
` 
if($id) {
    if($id == 'name' && $class =='aplha-desc') {
      $query .= ' SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY name DESC';
    }
  }
`

Comment: 6 запросов для каждого случая не надо писать :) Автоматизируйте - например, пусть sortby_id передает массив, а РНР его разбирает и строит запрос. Главное, не забудьте защититься от инъекций.

Comment: извините за дотошность, но могли бы вы показать как именно это делать через массив

Comment: Дотошность - это полезная в жизни штука :) Покажу пример выше, в своем ответе.

Comment: спасибо. Буду тестировать!